# Bulk indexing multiple documents at once in Spring Data ElasticSearch, how?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

There doesn't seem to have anything related to bulk operation like bulk indexing multiple documents at once in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html

Is it even supported? Any example?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try as follow:

For ex: Say you have 10 documents which you want to bulk index.

```
BulkRequest bulkRequest=new BulkRequest();
```

Then for each document(within for loop)

```
  bulkRequest.add(new IndexRequest(doc.getIndex())
                    .id(doc.getId())
                    .source(doc.getSource().toString(), XContentType.JSON));
```

finally,make a call to Elasticsearch using RestHighLevelClient instance.

```
BulkResponse bulkResponse=restHighLevelClientInstance.bulk(brb, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Note : BulkRequest, IndexRequest and BulkResponse are classes from Elasticsearch.

Comment: Are you talking about Elasticsearch Java API or Spring Data ElasticSearch?